# Copy content from one spreadsheet to another without IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to create bidirectional synchronisation of some content between two Google Sheets. My script is working when:

- the source and destination ID of the sheets are the same AND have the ID of the active spreadsheet

SO, THIS WORKS:

```
function myFunction() {

 var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID-OF-ACTIVE-SPREADSHEET");
 var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID-OF-ACTIVE-SPREADSHEET");

 var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet1");
 var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet2");

 var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:A4");

 // destination, columnStart, columnEnd, rowStart, rowEnd
 sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destinationSheet, 2, 2, 3, 7);

}
```

But when I replace the destination ID with the ID of another spreadsheet, it doesn't work.

Could it have something to do with permissions?

I have tried to publish both spreadsheets.

THIS DOESN'T:

```
...

 var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID-OF-ACTIVE-SPREADSHEET");
 var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID-OF-ANOTHER-SPREADSHEET");

...
```

Since I'm trying to create bidirectional sync I don't think I can use IMPORTRANGE.

[Source SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10cop2QTY2JdVEL7-0jSkd9f9k3GIKEdSvVlL-a9ED_A/edit?usp=sharing)

[Destination SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13aEvkEjjTJge1aBHXCwRXNwzndARIZnY4FeGVNYL-HE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share sample sheets with the script attached?  Without being able to debug the specifics, it's hard to say exactly what is the problem.

Comment: Source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10cop2QTY2JdVEL7-0jSkd9f9k3GIKEdSvVlL-a9ED_A/edit?usp=sharing

Destination: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13aEvkEjjTJge1aBHXCwRXNwzndARIZnY4FeGVNYL-HE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like copyValuesToRange doesn't communicate outside the spreadsheet, here is a working solution:

```
function onChange() {

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceData = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A8").getValues();
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID-OF-ANOTHER-SPREADSHEET").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  targetSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A8").setValues(sourceData);
}
```

PS: this also enables bidirectional sync between spreadsheets, just add a copy of this code on both spreadsheet A and B and replace "ID-OF-ANOTHER-SPREADSHEET" with the ID of the other spreadsheet. And then define the from- and to range in place of the "A1:A8".